# psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: error when creating an ir.cron model in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, cron, odoo, psycopg2

Hey guys I'm trying to automate an action with this code below, however, I keep getting this traceback error.

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "model_id" of relation "ir_act_server" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (308, Log User Changes , ir.actions.server, null, null, action, 1, 2021-05-06 03:33:44.223409, 1, 2021-05-06 03:33:44.223409, ir_cron, code, 5, null, null, # Available variables:
#  - env: Odoo Environment on which the a..., null, null, null, null, null, null, null, days, specific, null, user_id, null, null, f, null).
```

This is my ir.cron in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="log_res_groups" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Log User Changes </field>
            <field name="active" eval="True" />
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="doall">1</field>
            <field name = "state">code</field>
            <field name="model" eval="'res.users'" />
            <field name="function" eval="'group_change'" />
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Here's the function that should be called in the inherited user model.

```
 @api.multi
    def group_change(self, vals):
        for rec in self:
            get_curr_group_num = rec.num_of_groups
            res = super(Users, rec).write(vals)
            get_after_group_num = rec.num_of_groups
            if get_curr_group_num > get_after_group_num:
                _logger.info("Admin user %s, removed %s from group", rec.env.user.name, rec.name)
                return res
            elif get_curr_group_num < get_after_group_num:
                _logger.info("Admin user %s, added %s to a group", rec.env.user.name, rec.name)
                return res
            else:
                return res
```

Any reason why I could be getting the error? How to fix it?

Comment: You did not provide a value for `model_id` field. You can check the odoo 12 [ir_cron_data.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_cron_data.xml#L5) file

Comment: @Kenly Thanks but this leads to another question. One of my functions override the write method and I don't know what to pass in the parameter from xml. `group_change() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'`

Comment: The `group_change` function needs the `vals` argument. You can find an example in the event module where they passed an argument from the [Event: Mail Scheduler](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/event/data/event_data.xml#L9) to the [run](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/event/models/event_mail.py#L155 function). When odoo calls `group_change`, `self` should be an empty record set.